# What cartoon is featured in Britney Spears’ ‘Break the Ice’ video?

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

It looks really Marvel-ish and comic-y like Batman... kinda, but what is it?

It kinda plays in the entire video. Does anyone know what it is?

Comment: Looks like it's just a cartoon made for this video with Britney as the hero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Break_the_Ice_(Britney_Spears_song)#Music_video), the music video is an **original creation** for the artist. It was directed by [Robert Hales](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Hales_(director)) and draws influence from various Japanese manga series.

[Rolling Stone Magazine](http://www.rollingstone.com/music/news/britney-spears-break-the-ice-video-to-premiere-today-fandemonium-ensues-20080312) described it thusly;

> "Britney Spears is set to premiere her new anime-infused video for
>   "Break The Ice" at 6:30pm EST over at BlackoutBall.com. The third
>   single from Spears' Blackout, **the video is reportedly pretty much a
>   remake of Brit's own Mission: Impossible-inspired "Toxic" video,
>   except animated**. "